# strip span tags from string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, strip, replace

I am wanting to take the text value of a p tag when I press enter

```
$.keynav.enterDown = function () {
  var accom = $('#suggestions p.keynavon').html();
  alert(accom);

}
```

This is working great but the results contain `<span>`  and `</span>` tags, is there anyway I can strip those tags from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text, which sounds like what you're after, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), like this:

```
$.keynav.enterDown = function () {
  var accom = $('#suggestions p.keynavon').text();
  alert(accom);
}
```

If you actually need to strip the `<span>` tags specifically, clone the content (as to not affect the original) and replace them with their inner content via [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), like this:

```
$.keynav.enterDown = function () {
  var accom = $('#suggestions p.keynavon').clone()
                .find('span').replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; })
                .end().html();
  alert(accom);
}
```

Comment: Cheers nick, i totally forgot about .text!

Would you be able to help me with something else?

is there anyway to take the text and then remove the characters(rest of text) after a - symbol and then remove the - itself so eg.

"some - text"    would become

"some"
?

Comment: @AJFMEDIA - I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after, but yes you can using `.indexOf()` to get the position of what you're after the slice or substring around that, I'd ask a question with an example of what you're after, input and desired result :)