# Jquery: Strip all specific HTML tags from string

Tags: jquery

I have a variable that contains a string of text and html tags, such as:

```
var temp = "<div>Some text</div><p>More text<span>here</span></p><p>Even more</p>";
```

I would like to remove all tags of a certain type. Let's say all `p` and `span` tags for example.

This is the best I can come up with:

```
var temp = "<div>Some text</div><p>More text<span>here</span></p><p>Even more</p>";
var $temp = $(temp);
$("p", $temp).replaceWith("foo");
alert($temp.html());  //returns "Some text"
```

The closest response I could find is this answer by Nick Craver: [strip span tags from string with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797385/strip-span-tags-from-string-with-jquery).

Comment: edited question: p tags and span tags are what I want to replace. But this may change in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VwTHF/1/

```
$('span, p').contents().unwrap();
```

[`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) will get the elements and text within each such tag, and [`.unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) will remove the element wrapping each content section.

Based on your current approach it would look something like this:

```
var temp = "<div>Some text</div><p>More text<span>here</span></p><p>Even more</p>";
var $temp = $(temp);
$temp.find('span, p').contents().unwrap().end().end();
```

If you want to continue targeting the original object, you have to use `.end()` to clear the filter.

Comment: Hope I didn't misunderstand your question. You are just trying to get rid of the tags but leave the text right?

Comment: Yes, I just want to remove certain tags and keep the text and all other tags. But I could not get the above to work in this example: [http://jsfiddle.net/nEFhA/]

Comment: @iammatthew2 It works perfectly. You forgot to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/WPpqE/ (you have to specify the framework to use in the options on the left)

Comment: Indeed it does - thanks! Now how do I run that against a string contained in a variable? I've unsuccessfully tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/PgJnW/

Comment: @iammatthew2 That works, but you have to be careful with which jQuery object you target -- http://jsfiddle.net/VwTHF/ I updated my answer above. If you want to continue targeting the original object, you have to use `.end()` to clear the filter.

Comment: Note: `.html()` will only return the contents of an element -- only the `div` contents. `.text()` will return everything. http://jsfiddle.net/VwTHF/1/

Comment: @iammatthew2 See comment above :)

Comment: To show in an alert? I can't think of any trivial way to accomplish that. `.html()` ignores the text that's not wrapped in an element and `.text()` ignores the html tags. jQuery really isn't intended to be a string manip library -- these methods will work well with DOM manip tho. For example if you append `$temp` to an element in the DOM, it will render the appropriate text wrapped in the correct elements (even though you can't see it in alert)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you or anyone else recommend a string manip library?

Comment: @iammatthew2 Would javascripts native regex abilities be fine?

Comment: That may be my only choice, but I was trying to find a way to avoid using javascript and reg ex since I've heard it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [jquery plugin HTML Clean](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/). In the example they provide:

```
$.htmlClean("<H1 class=\"header\"><P>Nested P Test</H1>", {format:true});

=> 
<h1>
        Nested P Test
</h1>
```

You can replace specific tags with `{removeTags:[p]}` and it will still render the contents just not the tag.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try, but I was thinking that Jquery could take care of this with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar: keep a block of text from containing any HTML tag other than `<b>`, `<i>` or `<u>`. This question and several others pointed me towards my own function:

```
function cleanNonFormattingTags(htmlContents) {
    if (htmlContents && htmlContents.length) {
        var result = '';
        htmlContents.each(function () {
            var $child = $(this), type = $child.prop('tagName'), isTextNode = this.nodeName == "#text";
            if (isTextNode) {
                result += this.textContent;
            }
            else if (type == 'B' || type == 'U' || type == 'I' || type == 'BR') { // Allow only these types of tags
                var innerContent = cleanNonFormattingTags($child.contents());
                var $newTag = $(document.createElement(type)).html(innerContent);
                result += $newTag[0].outerHTML;
            }
            else {
                result += cleanNonFormattingTags($child.contents());
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
    return htmlContents.text();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'll follow up on @nbrooks because his answer is very close to what you want, but not quite. @nbrooks hit on the solution by noting that html() gives you the data that is wrapped in a tag. The solution therefore is to wrap your HTML in a tag. This should do the trick for you:

```
var temp = "<div>Some text</div><p>More text<span>here</span></p><p>Even more</p>";
$("<span>" + temp + "</span>").find('span,p').
  contents().unwrap().end().end().html()`
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/18u5Ld9g/1/ for an example.

As a more general function:

```
function stripTags(html, tags) {
  // Tags must be given in CSS selector format
  return $("<span>" + html + "</span>").find(tags).
    contents().unwrap().end().end().html();
}
```